# How to call strfttime after casting a column to a 'Date'

Tags: pyspark

In my data frame in pyspark, I create a new column which casts an existing column to a `Date`,

```
df = df.filter(....)
            .withColumn('Date',col('Time').cast('date'))\
```

My question is how can I run strfttime so that I just get the Year and Month of that date?

I tried doing

```
    .withColumn('Month',col('Time').cast('date').strftime("%Y-%m"))\
```

I get error saying 'TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strftime` is not a pyspark function.
try the [date_format](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.date_format.html) function instead.